# UIView animation shadowPath doesn't follow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-animations

I have a `UIView` with a `expand` function that I made.
When I call this function, the UIView stays centered, and I expand its width.

The issue is that my `UIView` has a `shadow`, with a `shadowPath`. Whenever I expand it, the shadow is imediatly expanded to the maximum width the view will get at the end of the animation, instead of following the bounds.

```
func expand() {
    guard self.expanded == false else {
        return
    }

    let originX = self.frame.origin.x
    let originY = self.frame.origin.y
    let originWidth = self.frame.width
    let originHeight = self.frame.height
    let newWidth = self.frame.width * 2

    let newRect = CGRect(x: originX - ((newWidth - originWidth) / 2), y: originY, width: newWidth, height: originHeight)

    self.expanded = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.frame = newRect
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (completed) in
    }
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` explicitly (but privately) chooses which of its layer's properties to implicitly animate, and `shadowPath` is not one of them. You have to animate it yourself.

Comment: How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Type `CABasicAnimation tutorial` in your favorite search engine.